# Pig game in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a pig game in python. Here is my code:

```
from random import *
roll_q = raw_input('would you like to roll')
if roll_q == (' yes'):
    while True:
        num1 = randint(1,6)
        print str(randint)
        if randint == 1:
            print('your turn is over')
            total = 0
        else:
         num1 = randint(1,6)
         print ('you got ') + str(randint) + ('points')
         total = randint
         print str(total)
         total=total + randint
         cont_q = raw_input('would you like to continue playing')
         if cont_q == ('yes'):
                print ('awesome')
         else:
                print ('ok')
else:
    print ('awesome')
```

When I ran this program I got asked if I wanted to roll and printed something. But then it gave me an error I didn't understand.

```
would you like to roll yes
<bound method Random.randint of <random.Random object at 0x89b010>>
you got <bound method Random.randint of <random.Random object at 0x89b010>>points
<bound method Random.randint of <random.Random object at 0x89b010>>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/centralcity/Desktop/Computer Science!/pig game", line 15, in <module>
    total=total + randint
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instancemethod' and 'instancemethod'
```

Please help me understand the error and why my program isn't printing right. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `total = randint` which is not a randint but a instancemethod

Comment: Please justify any downvotes.  I upvoted the question to bring it back to neutral.  Questions with a synopsis, source code, expected behavior, actual behavior, and a traceback are absolutely golden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep saying `randint` where you should say `num1`. After you call `randint` with `randint(1,6)` you store the result in `num1`, so the lines afterward should refer to `num1`.

```
if roll_q == (' yes'):
    while True:
        num1 = randint(1,6)
        print str(num1)
        if num1 == 1:
            print('your turn is over')
            total = 0
        else:
         num1 = randint(1,6)
         print ('you got ') + str(num1) + ('points')
         total = num1
         print str(total)
         total=total + num1
         cont_q = raw_input('would you like to continue playing')
         if cont_q == ('yes'):
                print ('awesome')
         else:
                print ('ok')
```

Comment: I think this explanation is probably clearer than mine, because it gets right to what he was most likely trying to do instead of starting off general and then trying to approach from that side.

Comment: That was a pretty stupid mistake, I'm new to python and I the syntax doesn't come natural yet. I would upvote you guys if I could.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you always need parentheses to call a function, even if there are no arguments. So, this line:

```
total = randint
```

… doesn't call `randint`. Instead, it just makes `total` another name for the `randint` function itself.

So, when you do this:

```
total=total + randint
```

… you're trying to add together two functions. And that doesn't make any sense.

What you probably want to do is something like this:

```
total = randint(1, 6)
# …
total = total + randint(1, 6)
```

Or maybe, since you've already done `num1 = randint(1, 6)`, what you wanted was:

```
total = num1
# …
total = total + num
```

If it's not clear what the difference is between the two: The first one rolls a brand new die and assigns the result to `total`, then rolls another new die and adds the result to `total`. The second one assigns the result of the previous die roll (the value in `num1`) to total, and then adds that same value to `total` again.

---

You have similar problems in multiple other places, like doing `print str(randint)` (which will print out "`<bound method Random.randint of <random.Random object at 0x89b010>>`" where you probably wanted `print num1` (which will print out something like `2`).

Answer (score 0):

`randint` is a method. You should call it:

```
total = randint(1, 20)
```

As I understand your code you should replace all `randint` (without parentheses) to `num1`. You've already called `randint` and assigned its return value to `num1`.

Answer (score 0):

You're assiging total to the function randint.

```
total = randint
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple think-error, I believe. At the top of your while loop, you assign to a variable `num1`. But then instead of using `num1`, you use `randint` (which is not a variable), when you clearly meant to use `num1`.

```
while True:
    num1 = randint(1,6)
    print str(randint)
    if randint == 1:
        ...
```

Replace `randint` with `num1` above (and similarly in the `else` clause), and you should be fine.